# Can I say --> Send me a scanned copy of "rear of the card"?

Tags: word-usage

Let's say I have some document which is printed on both sides. I need scanned copy of both sides. I have already got the front part of it and need the back of it now. Can I say --> send me a scanned copy of "**rear of the card**" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A card has two faces: front and back.

You would say

> Send me a scanned copy of the *back* of the card

Comment: Also, since you've already received one side, you could also say, "Send me a scan of the other side of the card, too."

Answer (score -1):

This phrasing could work if copies of both sides are needed:

> Send me a scanned copy of your ID (recto + verso)

More about *recto* and *verso* can be found [here](https://wiktenauer.com/wiki/Recto_and_verso).

Comment: I've never seen "recto" and "verso" used except referring to pages in a book/leaflet/etc, but even in that context they're rather obscure words which many English speakers would not understand. I wouldn't at all advise using them in this situation.